# create a list of pd.Series from a panda DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, list, subset, series

I have a DataFrame with a lot of columns, and a list of the column names I want to pass to an algorithm. The algorithm requires that I pass in argument not a dataframe but a list where each element is one of my `pd.Series` columns.

I think this question might already have been answered but I can' find... If there a function or method to achieve this transformation *data.Frame => list of pd.Series*?

Some code to show my desired output with 2 columns but my use case if with dozens of them, so I can't write it manually:

```
mydf = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'a': {0: 1, 1: 2}, 'b': {0: 3, 1: 3}, 'c': {0: 10, 1: 3}})
my_list_of_columns=["a", "b"]
desired_output = [mydf.a, mydf.b]
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use list comprehension:

```
desired_output = [mydf[x] for x in my_list_of_columns]
print (desired_output)
[0    1
1    2
Name: a, dtype: int64, 0    3
1    3
Name: b, dtype: int64]
```

Or convert to [`to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) with `to_dict(orient='series')` and get values of `dict`, but ordering should be changed in `python under 3.6`:

```
desired_output = list(mydf[my_list_of_columns].to_dict(orient='series').values())
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
import pandas as pd

mydf = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'a': {0: 1, 1: 2}, 'b': {0: 3, 1: 3}, 'c': {0: 10, 1: 3}})

desired_output = []
l = list(mydf)

for i in l:
    desired_output.append(list(eval('mydf.' + i)))


print(desired_output)
```